# How do i line up text on the horizontal axis, such as operating hours of a business?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to output the operating hours of a business with the operating hours lined up on the horizontal axis, so it looks something like the google output when you search up a business.

The only thing i could think of was to put spaces and line them up in my code but even when doing that the output on my phone screen is all messed up.

```
<Text style = {styles.date}>Monday:    {selectedbusiness.monday}</Text>
<Text style = {styles.date}>Tuesday:   {selectedbusiness.tuesday}</Text>
<Text style = {styles.date}>Wednesday: {selectedbusiness.wednesday}</Text>
<Text style = {styles.date}>Thursday:  {selectedbusiness.thursday}</Text>
<Text style = {styles.date}>Friday:    {selectedbusiness.friday}</Text>
<Text style = {styles.date}>Saturday:  {selectedbusiness.saturday}</Text>
<Text style = {styles.date}>Sunday:    {selectedbusiness.sunday}</Text>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>
 <Text>satday:</Text>
 <Text>{selectedbusiness.saturday} </Text>

</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by separating them into separate rows.

Try the below snippet

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
    <View>
      <Text>Monday</Text>
      <Text>Tuesday</Text>
      <Text>Wednesday</Text>
      <Text>Thursday</Text>
      <Text>friday</Text>
      <Text>Saturday</Text>
      <Text>Sunday</Text>
    </View>
    <View>
      <Text>{selectedbusiness.monday}</Text>
      <Text>{selectedbusiness.tuesday}</Text>
      <Text>{selectedbusiness.wednesday}</Text>
      <Text>{selectedbusiness.thursday}</Text>
      <Text>{selectedbusiness.friday}</Text>
      <Text>{selectedbusiness.saturday}</Text>
      <Text>{selectedbusiness.sunday}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
```